# Variable is changing into a list causing ValueError: Use a.any() or a.all() Opencv Python

Tags: python, opencv, bounding-box

I'm writing a piece of code that will check if a bounding rectangle created around a shape lies within another fixed rectangle. This is the section of code where the error is present:

```
rectangle = cv2.rectangle(frame, (150, 50), (450, 400), (0, 255, 0), 2)

if ID != -1:
    cnt = contours[ID]
    x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    x2 = x+w
    y2 = y+h

if x > 150:
    if y > 50:
        if x2 < 450:
            if y2 < 400:
                print "inside"
```

N.B Previous parts of the code find the largest contour and draw a bounding rectangle around it. This part is working fine, I just thought I'd mention it for a bit of context.

The error im getting is:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

The problem is, the program works for a while, printing inside succeessfully when the shape is inside the rectangle. However after a while the program crashes and displays the error message.

From this I'm thinking the variable `x` is converting into a list for some reason as this is the line the error occurs.

Would anyone know how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Where does x get its value when ID is equal to -1?

Comment: Are you using `numpy` in this program by chance?

Comment: Is this due to an indent issue? Should `if x...` and other comparisons only take place if `ID != -1`

Comment: I am using numpy, yes. I think thats it now, I should have had it inside the if statement. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As Kevin and Gareth pointed out, it was an indentation error. when ID was -1, x was not getting assigned any value (same with y, x2, y2).